# PHP nested if syntax error

Tags: php

I have a weird syntax issue relating to nested `if` statements.

This code errors:

```
if(true):
    if(true){
        var_dump(true);
    }
else:
    var_dump(false);
endif;
```

This code does not error (note the added `;`):

```
if(true):
    if(true){
        var_dump(true);
    };
else:
    var_dump(false);
endif;
```

What gives?

Comment: the `;` is expected after endif. also PLEASE @anybody dont use the if(): endif; syntax :P

Comment: Could be just my opinion, but I always viewed that syntax as a horrible horrible perl artifact. (+1 n00b). I'd like to add this is bad in while loops as well (damn popular in wordpress).

Comment: @n00b and @Christian Sciberras it is intended for PHP templating I believe and not for in methods etc. It is useful when you have PHP logic mixed with HTML as it is easier to read than a floating curly brace which could be to close an if or a while or for etc. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: if you have PHP mixed with HTML you have a problem allready ;P but good point ^^

Comment: @Treffynnon - What if you had several ifs? To fix the problem you mentioned, the best method is to create a comment at the end of each bracket, describing what the block was for. Many people are adopting this practice... On the other hand, that syntax is awfully confusing and prone to many errors - I've seen this happen a lot in wordpress.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras Yes, there are alternatives. I was just pointing out that jumping on it as not having a purpose is short sighted and not necessarily correct in every instance.

Comment: I didn't say it does not serve a purpose, I just said there are better ways to accomplish something that was flawed in the first place.

Comment: That's all tomato/tomato really. I find the colon syntax more readable when the end of the block is far from the beginning and/or there's a lot nesting. Don't diss it, learn to appreciate it

Comment: @Treffynnon - thank you for being the voice of reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Note:
>
> Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported.
> ```

This is from the notes in the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 5):

It's because the else is assigned to the inner if without the ;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found a valid answer to it. I changed the OP's code:

```
if(true):
   if(true){
       var_dump(true);
   }
else:
   var_dump(false);
endif;
```

to the following:

```
if (true) :
    {
        if (true) {
            var_dump ( true );
        } else {
            var_dump ( false );
        }
    }
endif;
```

which successfully ran and printed `true`.

The only change I made was that **I wrapped the nested `if` in a block.**

Simplified code:

```
if (true) :
    {
        if (true)
            var_dump ( true );
        else
            var_dump ( false );
    }
endif;
```

Note that I am using PHP `7.0.0`.