# Why Is This Generating A Division By Zero Error?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have been round and round on this and can't work out why this is throwing a "Division By Zero" error. This is my code:

```
  $complete = 0;
  $pending = 0;
  $incomplete = 0;
  $overall = 0;

  foreach ($allProgress as $oneProgress):
    if ($oneProgress['progress'] == 'complete') {
      $complete++;
      $overall++;
    }
    elseif ($oneProgress['progress'] == 'pending') {
      $pending++;
      $overall++;
     }
     else {
       $incomplete++;
       $overall++;
     }
     endforeach;

     echo $complete; // This is 2
     echo $overall; // This is 9

     $percentageComplete = ($complete / $overall) * 100;

     echo $percentageComplete;
```

I get a Division by Zero error on the line `$percentageComplete = ($complete / $overall) * 100;` I have checked with `is_int` on the two variables and they are integers. I am at a loss, is there a way of diagnosing what is happening here?

**EDIT**

More complete code below, including details of the array:

```
$section1 = $blockName . 'LeadershipAndCommunicationKeyTasks';
$section2 = $blockName . 'CurriculumKeyTasks';
$section3 = $blockName . 'TimetableAndPlanningKeyTasks';

$one = $kirby->user()->$section1()->yaml();
$two = $kirby->user()->$section2()->yaml();
$three = $kirby->user()->$section3()->yaml();

$allProgress = array_merge($one, $two, $three);

$complete = 0;
$pending = 0;
$incomplete = 0;
$overall = 0;

foreach ($allProgress as $oneProgress):
  if ($oneProgress['progress'] == 'complete') {
    $complete++;
    $overall++;
  }
  elseif ($oneProgress['progress'] == 'pending') {
    $pending++;
    $overall++;
  }
  else {
    $incomplete++;
    $overall++;
  }
endforeach;

$percentageComplete = ($complete / $overall) * 100;

echo $percentageComplete;
```

`print_r($allProgress)` gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => cumla0or
            [progress] => complete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => px1agxwc
            [progress] => complete
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => 8fs8d7ps
            [progress] => pending
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => m5z0lxna
            [progress] => pending
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => k46l0zaw
            [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => kykg3dk4
            [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => vatgjyib
            [progress] => pending
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => xnlmswue
            [progress] => incomplete
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [autoid] => bb04psb8
            [progress] => pending
        )

)
```

If `$overall` is initially set to 1 everything runs fine.

Comment: It makes no sense if echoing `$overall` truly gives 9. It could be 1) that's not the actual line the error refers to or 2) it's not that line that echoes 9. Please do `var_dump` of all four variables immediately after the loop.

Comment: `var_dump` of all 4 variables gives: `int(2) int(4) int(3) int(9)`

Comment: Seems weird. Guess you would know which line number the error occurs. Not that its a solution but what happens if you set `$overall = 1` initially?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini OP has `++` in all those conditions in the block, including the `else`

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://3v4l.org/D29iN). There's something you're not including in the question. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @GetSet if I set `$overall = 1` initially it runs fine....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506700/php-nested-if-syntax-error

Comment: Then perhaps its your `foreach` syntax. Try it with curlys `{}` as opposed to colon on end. If so then of course you wont need `endforeach;` Maybe your current syntax doesn't make it a code block as expected.

Comment: @GetSet That shouldn't be the issue. I used the same syntax in the fiddle I linked and it worked.

Comment: Agree @El_Vanja, the `else` condition will increment past 0 in the worse case scenario

Comment: But could be a bug in the dev environment terms of whichever php server is in play

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone - I am still trying to debug it but I think, as suggested, it is an environment issue as I can't reproduce elsewhere

Comment: If the `foreach` is working (which it must be if you can echo out a `9`). Then I'm not sure what environment issue would would suddenly reset it to `0`... Have you copy/pasted the entire file?

Comment: I have pasted everything now, including the array contents

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I suggest you don't handle `$overall` in the loop. Its value is known before you start iterating and is equal to `count($allProgress)`.

Comment: What happens if you take `$overall++` out of the `if` statements and put it at the start (or end) of the `foreach`?